# How to remove the Program Files folder from a non-system drive

Tags: windows-10, windows-store-app, microsoft-store

Sometime ago I installed a game using the "Xbox (beta)" app for Windows 10.

The program asked me where to install the game. I choose the D: drive. Then the program told me to make the D: suitable for installation first, so I changed the default install location for Apps to D: in the Windows Settings.

The program was installed on the D: drive. After installation I changed back the default install location for Apps to C:

Later I decided to move all the games to a new drive, I uninstalled all the games and reinstalled using the new drive. Then I removed from D: the following folders:

**DeliveryOptimization, Program Files, WindowsApps, WpSystem**

After a reboot I found that "Program Files" came back on D:, with one folder in it named "ModifiableWindowsApps".

I used SysInternals Process Monitor to find the process that was creating the folder. It appeared to be: C:\WINDOWS\system32\svchost.exe -k wsappx -p -s AppXSvc.

So the folder was created by svchost apparently checking some Microsoft Store stuff and then decided it has to create a D:\Program Files.

I also checked all of the installed Microsoft Store Apps using Get-AppxPackage. Non of the Store Apps use D: as the Install Location.

So I am stuck with this unnecessary Program Files folder and want to know how I can stop Windows from creating this folder.

Comment: First off, if this folder was created on this drive as per your instructions, and if it's in use by a running Windows service, you have to stop the service in question before you can do anything. Then, there are methods to delete a folder AND its entire content, usually involving third-pary programs like Unlocker (very good) or by adding a entry in your contextual menu to "Take ownership" of any non-system file or folder on your PC. The second method is explained here (https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3841-add-take-ownership-context-menu-windows-10-a.html), and I'd go with it if I were you.

Comment: I must add that this folder might well be created again by the same service or application if you still use it. EDIT: if you're reticent to install .reg files downloaded from the Internet, as you should be, you can download them, right-click on them and choose Modify. The content will be displayed in Notepad, and you'll be able to check what they're actually going to do on your PC.

Comment: Brute force changes can create more issues than solutions. I have not ever seen a solid practical reason to shift Windows Workstation away from Drive C:.  You might be best to back up and install Windows properly.

Comment: @Didier
I know how to remove the folders, I also did. The problem is that the folder is reappearing after a reboot. There are no programs or services using the folder after it has been recreated.

Comment: You have uninstalled the Xbox Beta application on Windows 10?

Comment: That was my next question too. If you have uninstalled the program that created this folder when you asked it to, there's no reason for said folder to reappear. Open PowerShell as admin and type "Disable-Appv". This will disable the Applications Virtualization service in Windows. Then try to delete the folder again, reboot your PC and see if the folder is back on your D drive.

Comment: @Ramhound
Yes, I have uninstalled everything that was installed after the first time I changed the default location. Although I did change it back directly after installing the game.So in theory nothing else should have been installed on D: without me knowing it.

Comment: @Didier, I did what you proposed, disabled appv, removed Program Files and rebooted. Program Files is back again.

Comment: One thing you can try, more as an experiment than as a permanent solution: take ownership of the whole drive, delete the offending folder, and set your D drive as read-only, then reboot.

Comment: I have had a similar experience in that I bought a new SSD solely for games and proceeded to move all of my Steam, Uplay, Epic, Rockstar etc. launchers and games to the new drive. Each one neatly in its own folder. No problem. Then comes time to do the same thing for the Xbox app and it creates these undeletable folders in the root of the drive, even before I've installed any games. It's like a virus. Utterly disgraceful behaviour. If 3rd party games devs can manage it why can't Xbox?!

Comment: Yes, Philip, it is frustrating. My Program Files folder is still there. No way to remove it.